# "have been reading" vs "have read"

Tags: perfect-constructions, present-perfect-progressive

Is that valid to say:

> I've been reading 3 books this week.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?, I know that it is better to say I've read 3 books this week, But Is it grammatical to say the sentence above?

Comment: Why you think it's not grammatical? Is there anything specific that you think it makes it wrong?

Comment: @Cardinal I've been told by my teacher that When we mention the number of times an action happened, the present perfect simple must be used.

Comment: Exactly. Michael Swan's view is so.

Answer (score 2):

If you **have read** three books this week, you have finished reading them.

If you **have been reading** three books this week, the implication is that you are continuing to read them.

It suggests that you have not completed any of them - and certainly not all of them.

**Have read** indicates that the action is complete.

**Have been reading** indicates that the action has continued up to the present.

Both are correct, depending on what you mean.

Comment: Would it be valid to say "I am reading 3 books" because the action is still ongoing?

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect continuous tense cannot be used to talk about **how much** something has happened or **how many times** something has happened *in total*. Instead, we use simple present perfect tense here.

> *'We have been painting two rooms since morning'.* (incorrect)
> But *'We have painted two rooms since morning'.*(correct)

> *'He has been doing it twice.'* (incorrect)
> But *'He has done it twice.'* (correct)

> *'I have been reading three books this week.'* (incorrect)
> But *'I have read three books this week.'* (correct)

Comment: I have given the answer on the basis of the view of Michael Swan. If anyone disagrees, please refute my answer with logic and reference instead of downvoting the answer whimsically.

Answer (score 0):

"I've been reading 3 books this week." is not correct, because it means none of the 3 books are finished, whereas you already finished 2 of them.

It is clear that you have finished 2 books already, and you are reading the 3rd one.

So, with reference to your other questions;

1- you can't say "I have read 3 books", which means "I have finished 3 books" which would not be true.

2-Nor you can say "I am reading 3 books this week" because it means you are reading all 3 books at the same time, which is not the case in your situation.

So, I think you should say **"This is the 3rd book I have been reading this week".** which means, I already finished 2 books and I am reading a 3rd one and the week is not finished yet.

Answer (score -2):

'I've been reading 3 books this week' is correct. It means that I started reading the books in the past and I am still reading them. The action is still going on.

'I have read 3 books this week' implies that I have already finished reading 3 books. I am not reading the books now. The action has ended.